# Object Oriented PHP to pass message to user upon success of function

Tags: php, forms, oop, post-redirect-get

I am new to OO php so this may seem basic..

Basically I have a list of courses a user can book. I have got it so the user can remove the course from their list, but I want a message to be displayed to them after they delete. I have done something similar to what I want here:

```
<form name="removecourse" action="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/user/<?php echo $current_user->first_name ; ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php the_id();?>" name="courseid" />
<input id="removebutton" type="submit" name="removecourse" value="Remove">
</form>
```

The form sends the required data to the same page, and at the top of that page is a check to see if the forms post name is present in $_POST[] like so:

```
    if(isset($_POST['removecourse']) && !empty($_POST['removecourse'])){        
    $courseManager->delete_post($_POST['courseid'], $_POST['cancel-reason']);
    echo $courseManager->delete_response;
};
```

This is where the Class and object part comes in...

```
    public $delete_response;

function delete_post($postid, $reason){

     //stuff to actually delete the post

    $this->delete_response = 'Thanks, your course has been removed.';

}
```

So here I am adding a value to the delete_response variable and calling it above at the top of the page. This works, but when I refresh the page the message is still there as I am resubmitting the POST. I am just wondering if what I am doing is along the right track, and how to implement a Post/Redirect/Get type functionallity to stop the messaage from appearing on page refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check, either your course has been already deleted, is it simple as that :).

Yours displaying it again because:

```
if(isset($_POST['removecourse']) && !empty($_POST['removecourse'])){
//is always true when posted again. 
}
```

You have to check the existiance

Comment: `isset( $_POST['removecourse'] ) && !empty( $_POST['removecourse'] )` === `!empty( ['removecourse'] )` because `empty` includes the check, whether the variable was set.

Comment: So your saying I have to check to see wether my course has been deleted? That would require a DB query or somethign along those lines yes??

Comment: actually its like that u need to check it, everyone is doing it like that. A dbquery is not that time consuming.